# How to prevent Component rendering in all Routes?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and trying to understand routing. I've define very basic Routes in my `App.js` component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Switch, BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './Routing/Header'
import Home from './Routing/Home'
import About from './Routing/About';
import Contact from './Routing/Contact';
import User from './Routing/User';
import FileNotFound from './Routing/FileNotFound';
import Game from './Components/Game'
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <div>

              <Header />

              <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
              <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
              <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
              <Route path="/user" component={User}/>
              <Route component={FileNotFound}/>
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>

          <Game />

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The `<Header />` Component is responsible for rendering the navbar. As you can notice the `App.js` component is rendering a `<Game />` component. Which in returns render on all components although I've defined the routes. 
[image: Component]
My question is:

> How can I prevent the Game component to render on other components
>   defined in Route?

What I'm missing in this approach? or is there a better approach than the one I'm using right now.

Comment: Where do you want to render `<Game />`, in which component?

Comment: Depends on what conditions are that you want it rendered. Not enough known from information given

Comment: Your `<Game/>` component is like a footer in your approach. Anything you place outside of your routing component will render in all routes. If you want to display `<Game/>` component specifically in some parts of your app, place this component directly to other specified components or make separate route for this component.

Comment: @MalikAwan Thank you, I understand. That is pretty simple. How idiotic of me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not routing `Game`, you should either put it inside one of your routed components or create a path for it otherwise will always render when app is rendered:

```
 <BrowserRouter>
    <div>

      <Header />

      <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
      <Route path="/user" component={User}/>
      <Route path ='/game'component={Game}/>
       <Route component={FileNotFound}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: That means, I should add it in a component or inside a route. I understand, Thank you for the answer

Comment: Exactly. Glad to help. Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you. I also need to ask this. Is it the right approach to add Routes or, are there some better ways to do it?

Comment: I've read many articles with different methods, some have defined routes in `Index.js` and some have mapped `<App />` in `<BrowserRouter>`

Comment: There is no right way to do it, everything depends on your use case. Definitively there is no harm in defining many routes.